# .asp web api how to bind/push complex data (table has data related to foreign table)

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-web-api2

As the title says, I don't know how to push data to model that has foreign table related to itself. Here is the example:

```
public class DonationDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DonationSession Session { get; set; }
    public DonationType Type { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckDate { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string DesignatedTo { get; set; }
    public float? DesignatedAmount { get; set; }
}

public class DonationSession
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DonationDetail> DonationDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

So user can create a list of donations, that is donation session, and single donation is related to donation detail. Now problem comes: when I bind data from frontend, how to deal with both models? Particularly, what should I push to "public virtual DonationSession Session" in "DonationDetail", and also, deal with the "ICollection<..> DonationDetails" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from JavaScript with the help of  HTTP Methods like this

```
var  DonationSession= {
Id : 0,
District : "TEST",
UserId : "123",
StartTime :"10-Jan-2016",
EndTime : "10-Jan-2016",       
DonationDetails : [{
    Name :"ABC",
    ID:"123",
    ...........

}]};
```

you can pass this(DonationSession) object with your http method call 
you can notice that DonationDetails property is an array you can add any number of items in to it.and pass that list to the web api function